# Adding a database in Pycharm

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.7

I have made a project in Pycharm using Django and a virtual environment using conda commands. By default the database added in it is db.sqlite3 but I want to change it to MySQL which I have preinstalled in my laptop. I also installed the database navigator package in the Pycharm and a connection with the preinstalled MySQL has been setup. But how to link it with my current project in place of db.sqlite3.

Comment: What does this have to do with Pycharm? You just need to change the DATABASES setting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the `settings.py` file and the `DATABASE` variable.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```